# How to transform observations between different binomial distributions?

Tags: data-transformation, binomial-distribution, proportion, poisson-binomial-distribution

#### Context

I am an instructor and I am trying to grade on a curve -- but using a more rigorous mathematical approach than other quick ways I've seen so far. (I'm also interested in this purely theoretically!)

Suppose students' grades could be modelled as a binomial distribution with a fixed mean (with big approximations obviously made). The number of "trials" is the integer number of points possible in the class, the number of "successes" is the number of points that student earned, and the distribution mean is the class average. I want to shift my class average from one distribution mean to another, and transform my students' grades accordingly.

#### Analogue from the Normal Distribution

If a class's grades were to follow a normal distribution with a mean of $\mu$ and a standard deviation of $\sigma$, and I wanted to transform a given student's grade ($x$) to a curved distribution with a mean of $\mu_C$ and standard deviation $\sigma_C$, I could equate the $z$-score of both distributions as follows:

$$
\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} = z\right) = \left( z_c = \frac{x_C-\mu_C}{\sigma_C} \right)
$$
Then, I could solve for the student's curved score, $x_C$, as follows: 
$$
x_C = \frac{\sigma_C}{\sigma}\left(x-\mu\right) + \mu_C
$$

#### My Question

If there are $n$ points possible in a class, and each student earns $x_i$ points (with $x_i\le n$), then the $i^{th}$ student will have a grade of $\hat{p}_i = \frac{x_i}{n}$, where $0 \le \hat{p}_i \le 1$. The class average is $p$. We'll assume that the distribution of $\hat{p}_i$ follows a binomial distribution. (If there's a better distribution -- perhaps the [Poisson binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution)?) let me know.)

**If I want to set a new class average from $p$ to $p_C$, how would I transform students' grades $p_i$ accordingly, *assuming* their grades follow a binomial distribution?**

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking but I have a couple questions:
1. Do you mean that $x_i$ follows a binomial distribution? $\hat{p}_i$ is not integral
2. As written you're assuming independence between a given students answers to questions - is this intentional?